# Windows 10 Accounts - Are Users with Admin Privileges the Same as Admins?

Tags: windows-10, permissions

I'm trying to sort out some file permission issues on Windows 10 and getting really confused because there are permission for users and permissions for administrators. I thought I had set myself up as an admin, but am I in fact just a user with admin privileges?

Are users with admin privileges the same as administrators?

According to the permissions listed, administrators have full control, but I don't. I'm currently setting "inheritance on all objects" whatever that means, and it's taking forever. I don't even know if that's what I should be doing. All I want is to be ale to access files from my main user account from a separate account which also has admin access. It's taken two hours of research and experiment so far. I'm rapidly falling out of love with Windows.

Comment: ACLs work just the same on Windows as any other OS - they just seem to take much, much longer to propagate. [QNAS has a reasonably comprehensive guide](http://qnapsupport.net/qnap-uygulamalari/kullanici-ve-klasor-olusturma/klasor-olusturma-ve-yetkilendirme/how-to-use-windows-acl-to-manage-user-permissions-on-the-qnap-nas/)

Answer (score 2):

> Are users with admin privileges the same as administrators?

In essence, yes. But that doesn't mean you can do anything.

In Windows XP and earlier, if you were Administrator, you basically could do anything. Because many users were administrators, viruses spread like crazy because they could easily infect systems.

To combat this, UAC (User Account Control) was implemented which changes the behavior of administrators.

A user can have administrative privileges, but actions performed by an administrator still have to be executed as administrator. If you are an administrator, and try to perform an action that only an administrator can do, you should get a popup for elevation, where you have to physically click yes.

This is done because programs do not have access to this window and thus cannot get administrative privileges.

If you run a program as administrator, any program spawned from that will have administrative access too. For example, if you run CMD as administrator, and from there start another program, both will have administrative privileges, but to start cmd as administrator, you would still need to press that yes button once.

File permissions work differently. You have rights or you don't. If you are member of the administrator group, and administrators have access, you can get in. If your own user is not a member, you will get an UAC prompt asking for permissions, which will then temporarily assign rights so you have access (which can take a long time to complete)

That said, Owners have rights that supersedes file permission rights.